# PHP date is one day ahead?

Tags: php, date

when I write `<?php echo date('d'); ?>` the day is always one day ahead? I've checked everything and it doesn't echo that on my other websites on the same database

Comment: Could you put some code please?

Comment: What code are you using it to write it out? Can you print out the timezone and make sure that it matches the other servers? Also make sure the server time is right.

Comment: Is that `d` supposed to be in quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [setting the timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to one of [these values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

For example, try this at the start of your script (with the appropriate timezone, of course):

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `date_default_timezone_set()`. Your server time is one day different from where you actually are.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 2):

The database may be the same, but the server is most likely different. The date is pulled from the hosting server.

A quick fix is to set [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Your other option, if you are hosting your own site, is to fix the date time settings on the server itself.